# Glass normal reflection problem

Tags: rendering, normal-map, glass

[image]

The normal map that I have set on the glass seems to reflect on the other side of the glass, how can I remove this?

object is bottle with thickness and a hollow inside + a subdivision modifier
[image]

[image: Node setup]

Normal map is only on the outside on both sides of the model

Comment: Hello :). You'll need to share more details. Your material, UV map, geometry and [perhaps share the .blend](https://pasteall.org/blend/)

Comment: Sorry, first time user :P

Comment: Are you using a solidify modifier to give it thickness?

Comment: yes, but its applied